# Ji Chen's lemma

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, reference-request

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u797276h2556237p27284705

In the solution of the VMF member, Ji Chen's lemma was mentioned. I asked VMF but have not received an answer yet. Could you provide me with some information about this theorem? I find it quite interesting. I have searched on AoPS and StackExchange but haven't found anything yet. Thank you!

Comment: @Gary Have you read the solution in the link above? It's not the Ji Chen inequality mentioned earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is Lemma 1 below. I discussed it some years ago.

**Lemma 1**: Let $a, b, c, u, v, w\ge 0$
such that
$$a + b + c = u + v + w, 
\quad ab + bc + ca = uv + vw + wu,
\quad abc \ge uvw.$$
Let $f(x)$ be a function with $f'''(x) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 0$.
Then
$$f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \ge f(u) + f(v) + f(w).$$

$\phantom{2}$

About VMF-er@AoPS's proof:

Let $u = v = 1 + t$ and $w = 1 - 2t$ for $t \le 1/2$.
We have
$$a + b + c = 3 = u + v + w$$
and
$$ab + bc + ca = 3 - 3t^2 = uv + vw + wu.$$
One can prove that
$$abc \ge (1 + t)^2(1- 2t) = uvw.$$

Now consider $g(x) = -\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 1}{2}}$. We have $g'''(x) \ge 0$ on $x \ge 0$. Thus, we have
$$g(a) + g(b) + g(c) \ge g(u) + g(v) + g(w) = 2g(1 + t) + g(1 - 2t).$$
The desired result follows.

$\phantom{2}$

**About Lemma 1**:

1. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t321f6h1669330_very_old_one
2. According to [csav10's post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1816436_inequality_about_power_sum),
   Vasc has posted in 1989, in the Romanian journal Gazeta Matematica A, no. 3, the following lemma which implies Lemma 1.

**Lemma 2**: Let
$f$ is a three differentiable function on interval $I$ and
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = c_1 + c_2 + c_3,
\quad a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 
= c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2$$
where $a_i, c_i\in I$. Then there is
$x \in I$ such that
$$f(a_1) + f(a_2) + f(a_3) - f(c_1) - f(c_2) - f(c_3) = \frac12(a_1a_2a_3 - c_1c_2c_3) f'''(x).$$

3. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1833674p12287381

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Math_fun2006 You are welcome.

Comment: Do you have a proof for lemma 2 or a source for it? I tried to search for it but couldn't find it because the source is too old.

Comment: I also asked about how to prove lemma 2 in the following link, 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659615/a-result-similar-to-the-intermediate-value-theorem
and if possible, I would appreciate your help with that! Thank you.

Comment: @Math_fun2006 It is nice to discuss Vasc's lemma.

Comment: The problem is too difficult, I can't think of a way to solve it!