# A result similar to the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request

During my search for a solution to the challenging math problem, I came across the following problem by mathematician Vasile Cîrtoaje.

I planned to use the intermediate value theorem, but I didn't understand why a third-order derivative appeared in the conclusion of the problem. This hindered my progress in finding a solution. The problem is stated as follows:

If $f$ is a three differentiable function on I and
$$a_1+a_2+a_3=c_1+c_2+c_3,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2,$$where $a_i,b_i\in$ I , then there is $x\in$ I such that
$$f(a_1)+f(a_2)+f(a_3)-f(c_1)-f(c_2)-f(c_3)=\frac 1{2}(a_1a_2a_3-c_1c_2c_3)f'''(x).$$

The source of the problem can be found at the following link:
[enter link description here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1816436_inequality_about_power_sum)

Comment: You mean the Mean Value Theorem, I presume.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Yes!

Comment: The third derivative almost surely comes from applying the MVT to $f''$, which itself arises from applying the MVT to $f'$, which will arise from applying the MVT to $f$.

Comment: It is in:  Vasile Cırtoaje, A class of inequalities with second order convex functions. Gazeta Matematica A, 1989. But I can not find the article. See:  Page 5 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5249.pdf

Comment: @River Li Thanks!